# How would I record the position of multiple objects, while still being scalable?

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to get three different 'List' objects to work together.

To sum up what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to save three different variables, but have them all be accessed together.

So if I say:

```
void main() {
    addStuff(1, 12, true);
}
void updateStuff(int i1, int i2, boolean b1) {
    list1.add(i1);
    list2.add(i2);
    list3.add(i3);
}
```

then that would save the three corresponding values.

Now, how would I go about retrieving these variables, while still having support for removing elements from the list (that is to say, if I remove one element from each list - the ones that correspond with each others.)

Apologies if I didn't explain myself clearly - I'll happily give more details if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use parallel arrays (or in this case lists) where one list of objects is likely to be more suitable.

Comment: Yeah, the general consensus seems to be that. I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably create some class that contains those two ints and one boolean.

Then you can have a single `List<YourClass>`.

```
public class YourClass 
{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private boolean c;

    public YourClass (int a, int b, boolean c) {
       this.a=a;
       this.b=b;
       this.c=c;
   }

   // add some getters and setters here
}

    void updateStuff(int i1, int i2, boolean b1) 
    {
        list.add(new YourClass(i1,i2,b1));
    }
```

This way you don't have to worry about synchronizing the lists when adding/removing elements, since you only have one list.

Comment: @DavidCa1226 Your comment makes no sense, as the same restrictions apply to your lists

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understood what you're trying to do from your comment on Eran's answer (it may be a good idea to provide this information on your question so more people can help you), you have a bunch of points on the cartesian plane and have to check if one is too close to another.
To avoid the need of so many checks each time you need this information you want to store it in some kind of data structure wich will be updated each time a new point is inserted.
Is it correct?

If so, you can create a graph representing this information:

```
public class MyPoints {
    private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<List<Boolean>> tooCloseGraph = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPoint(Point point){
        List<Boolean> newLine = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Point p : points){
            newLine.add(p.isTooClose(point));
        }
        newLine.add(true) //Assuming a point is too close to itself
        tooCloseGraph.add(newLine);
        points.add(point);
    }

    public boolean isTooClose(int a, int b){
        if(a > b)
            return tooCloseGraph.get(a).get(b);
        else
            return tooCloseGraph.get(b).get(a);
    }

    public boolean isTooClose(Point a, Pont b){
        return isTooClose(points.indexOf(a), points.indexOf(b));
    }
}
```

I have't tested it but I think it works.

Cheers!